# If exponentiation of a matrix is upper triangular show it is upper triangular itself

Tags: matrices

Consider $A$ which is a $n \times n$ invertible matrix with complex entries and $n \geq 1$, Suppose for every $k\geq2$, $A^k$ is upper triangular

I want to show that $A$ is upper triangular itself, honestly I don't know how to start and from where I start.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take the time to read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Please do not delete questions after you have been given an answer!

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ invertible matrix then its characteristic polynomial $\det(xI-A)$ reads
$$
c_0+c_1x+\dots+x^n,\qquad c_0=(-1)^n\det A\not=0.
$$
By Cayley-Hamilton theorem
$$
c_0I+c_1A+\dots+A^n=0.
$$
Thus
$$
c_0A+c_1A^2+\dots+A^{n+1}=0
$$
and since $c_0\not=0$ then
$$
A=-\frac{c_1A^2+c_2A^3+\cdots+A^{n+1}}{c_0}
$$
which is upper triangular by assumption.

Incidentally, note that the conclusion holds true even if $A$ is not invertible, as long as $c_1\not=0$. When $c_0=c_1=0$ there are counterexamples (e.g. $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ -1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$, $A^k=0$ for all $k\geq 2$).